# Overhead involved in nested sequences in F#

Tags: performance, f#, lazy-evaluation

I need to do excessive pattern matching against an xml structure, so I declared a type to represent the xml nodes. The xml is a multitree and I need to somehow iterate over the nodes. To make the tree enumerable, I use nested sequence comprehensions. My XML will never be too big, so simplicity beats performance in my case, but is the following code somehow dangerous for larger inputs, or would it be ok to leave it as it is.

```
type ElementInfo = { Tag : string; Attributes : Map<string, string> }
type Contents = 
    | Nothing
    | String of string
    | Elements of Node list
and Node =
    | Element of ElementInfo * Contents
    | Comment of string
    member node.PreOrder = 
        seq {
            match node with
            | Element (_, Elements children) as parent -> yield parent; yield! children |> Seq.collect (fun child -> child.PreOrder)
            | singleNode -> yield singleNode
        }
```

Comment: How large of inputs?  Everything is relative.

Comment: Small, like 7kB or so, but the question is more about, should I be avoiding nested sequence expressions, or does the compiler flatten them somehow anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought the call to `Seq.collect` might cause it to generate an `IEnumerable` per call, so I replaced it with a `for` loop and it produces the same output (via ILSpy).

That made me curious so I decompiled a simpler sequence expression I'd expect to be "flattened."

```ml
let rec infSeq n =
  seq {
    yield n
    yield! infSeq (n+1)
  }
```

The code to generate the next element in the sequence decompiles to this:

```cs
public override int GenerateNext(ref IEnumerable<int> next)
{
    switch (this.pc)
    {
    case 1:
        this.pc = 2;
        next = Test.infSeq(this.n + 1);
        return 2;
    case 2:
        this.pc = 3;
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    default:
        this.pc = 1;
        this.current = this.n;
        return 1;
    }
    this.current = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it calls itself recursively, generating a fresh `IEnumerable` each time. A quick test in FSI

```
infSeq 0 |> Seq.take 10000000 |> Seq.length
```

you can see there's a lot of GC:

```
> Real: 00:00:01.759, CPU: 00:00:01.762, GC gen0: 108, gen1: 107, gen2: 1
```

Compared to the C# version

```cs
public static IEnumerable<int> InfSeq(int n) {
    while (true) yield return n++;
}
```

in FSI:

```
> Real: 00:00:00.991, CPU: 00:00:00.998, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

It's faster and uses constant memory (no extra `IEnumerable`s).

I thought F# would generate a single `IEnumerable` for `yield!` in a tail position, but apparently not.

#### EDIT

The [spec confirms](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818836) this: `{| yield! expr |}` is elaborated as `expr`, that is, subsequences (recursive or otherwise) are not merged into a single `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, as it gives two statements: Yes, there is addition overhead that might be worthwhile to get rid of, if doing some HPC. On the other hand, in many scenarios it is going to be a non-issue.